# Defining a generic method using interface<t> as a parameter in C#.net

Tags: c#, generics

I am looking to add a method which would use interface and other T2 as parameters to a method. But it does not seem to work.

Here is the context:

```
public interface IDoSomething<T> where T : class
{
   IQueryable<T> GetSomething();
}
```

The implementation class is like:

```
public class DoSomething<T>: IDoSomething<T> where T : class
{
   IQueryable<T> GetSomething()
   {
     ////
   }
}
```

I am registering these to an IOC container. But I want to create a helper class which can be used for specific test scenarios where I can register individual classes and interfaces via a method like this:

```
public void Register<IDoSomething<T>,TEntity>()
where T : class
where TEntity : class , T
{}
```

Or like this :

```
public void Register<TEntity,TImplementation>()
where TEntity : IDoSomething<T>
where T : class
where TImplementation : class , T
{}
```

None of them seem to be valid syntax.

Any ideas how this should be?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I've understand you question correctly by I can suggest two variant's how to make syntax of those methods valid.
In declaration of generic method you need to specify type `T` to use it for definition of `IDoSomething<T>`.

You can declare `T` instead `IDoSomething<T>` and use `IDoSomething<T>` everywhere in code where you planed to use `T`:

```
public void Register<T, TEntity>()
    where T : class
    where TEntity : class, IDoSomething<T>
{}
```

Also you can declare `T` as third generic parameter:

```
public void Register<T, TEntity, TImplementation>()
    where T : class
    where TEntity : IDoSomething<T>
    where TImplementation : class, TEntity
{}
```

If it's not suitable for you situation please add code of generic method's that you want to write.